# Can I use <span> to achive this?

Tags: html, css

What can I use  to create this effect? and if I use `<span>` how can I position them properly, for example I tried to position them, but can't move `<span>` element to the left or right even with position absolute, only top and bottom. I have used this code

```
<span class="colors">
    <span class="white"></span>
    <span class="orange"></span>
    <span class="grey"></span>
    <span class="green"></span>
 </span>
```

[image: What is required]

Here is my result I want to place them like in first image how can I achieve that?
[image: what i have]

Comment: The question would look better with minimal pictures inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking multiple questions, one more general question, and one question specifically related on how to align your color pickers.

To answer the question posed in the title: Yes, you can use  to achieve that. `<span>` tags are `display: inline;` by default, meaning that, unlike a `div`, they will line up next to each other in the same line. HTML tags can be extended to do more or less whatever you'd like when it comes to layout and design, especially tags that don't carry some sort of attribute or variable, like `<div>`, `<section>`, `<span>`, etc. While it is true that these three tags have default browser definitions, you can use CSS to change these definitions very easily.

I sense that the more specific question (regarding how to lay out your color pickers) would be much easier to answer with an example of the markup you've written so far. From your screenshot, I will assume that you have some sort of grid system that puts each car and the corresponding information into a container, like so:

```
<div class="container">

<!-- Begin Car 1 -->
<div class="car">
 <img></img>
 <div class="colors">
  <button>Color1</button>
  <button>Color2</button>
  <button>Color3</button>
  <button>Color4</button>
 </div>
 <div class="info">
  <span>302 blah blah blah</span>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Car 1 -->

<!-- Begin Car 2, 3, etc... -->

<!-- End Container -->
</div>
```

Regardless, an easy way to lay this out would be using `display: flex;` and then both vertically and horizontally centering your colors using `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`, respectively.

So it would probably look something like this

```
<style>
 .colors > button {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 }
</style>
```

Hope this helped. Good luck with the rest of your layout.

Comment: thank you a lot, version with buttons works better I can move each element however I want with, span only top and bottom. I don't have to make grid for each color thats yet to complicated for me xD only position them properly, thanks mate ^.^

Comment: Your very first paragraph is all the reasons this question will soon be closed and deleted and all your work, along with the rep points gained, will be gone forever. You should have voted to close this, not answer it.

Comment: Sorry, new user here. Good to know @Rob, I'll do that next time. Thank you.

Comment: [Answer well asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)